How can I unmarshal an XML tag with 2 different types of nested content?
I am working with some XML that has mixed types of data in a single XML tag. The different type of content is dependent on the attribute value. I can either parse the string or the nested tags, but I can't figure out how to support both.
Is there any way to structure the struct to support different field types based on a tags attribute value?
Below is what I have so far:
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type CustomAttribute struct {
    AttributeID string `xml:"attribute-id,attr"`
    Value       string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Customer struct {
    CustomAttributes []CustomAttribute `xml:"custom-attribute"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := `
        <customer>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="shipmentChangelog">
                <value>06/16/2023 9:22:49 AM PST Shipment has been cancelled: 60686167</value>
                <value>06/22/2023 2:19:10 PM PST Product has been removed: {"id":"47606963","pid":"FBS100402080001"}</value>
            </custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="isCustomerImported">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="customerName">JohnDoe</custom-attribute>
        </customer>
    `

    var customer Customer
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &customer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the unmarshaled data
    for _, attr := range customer.CustomAttributes {
        fmt.Printf("Attribute ID: %s\n", attr.AttributeID)
        fmt.Printf("Value: %s\n", attr.Value)
    }
}


Are you sure "unmarshalling" is the right approach? Data binding works well when you are dealing with XML that maps well to the rigorous data structures of conventional programming languages. When you are dealing with semi-structured XML, other technologies may work better.

@MichaelKay I have tried messing around with regex to convert the values into a JSON string that I could parse later, but I have not figured that path out yet. Do you have other ideas?

Whatever you do, don't try parsing XML with regular expressions: always use a proper XML parser. My own preference is always to use an XML-specific language like XSLT or XQuery; the alternative is to parse to a generic XML tree model such as DOM (popular but horrible) or JDOM2 or XOM (less popular but much better). Having said that, I don't know what constraints go imposes.

You could go for a more sophisticated solution, but perhaps adding:
    Values      []string `xml:"value"`

to CustomAttribute is enough?
It works at least for your example: https://go.dev/play/p/r3mTdV0l-GO

I have tried that, but then you only get the nested values and not the single strings.
Attribute ID: shipmentChangelog Value: [06/16/2023 9:22:49 AM PST Shipment has been cancelled: 60686167 06/22/2023 2:19:10 PM PST Product has been removed: {"id":"47606963","pid":"FBS100402080001"}] Attribute ID: isCustomerImported Value: [] Attribute ID: customerName Value: []

@ATLChris: LGTM. What exactly is the problem? I've added a Go Playground link to the answer.
